# SWIG errors because of preprocessor directive

Tags: swig, c-preprocessor

We have a vendor that has provided us a C++ library and headers, that I'm trying to wrap using SWIG.  It appears that they are being too clever by a half with the preprocessor directives:

```
// top.h
#define DECLARE_WITH_COMMA(a) a,
```

and then

```
// foo.h
#include "top.h"

#define MY_TYPES(d) \
  d(One)   \
  d(Two)   \
  d(Three) \
  NumElems

enum MyTypes {
  MY_TYPES(DECLARE_WITH_COMMA)
};
```

Which is all a longwinded way of saying that when I try to run SWIG (version 2.0.4) on "foo.h", I get:

```
foo.h:12: Error: Syntax error in input(1).
```

So my question is what are my options here, given that I probably don't want to change the vendor-supplied headers?

Comment: Which is line 84?  Can you construct a minimal test-case based on the headers in question, and post it here?

Comment: Ok, code above now represents a complete test case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SWIG doesn't recurse into nested headers by default, so your `.i` file should look something like:

```
%module mymod

%{
#include "foo.h"
%}

%include "top.h"
%include "foo.h"
```

There is also a SWIG switch:

```
-includeall     - Follow all #include statements
```

but if you have system headers that may do more than you intend.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, what if `top.h` has an `#include` statement for another header file? I'm having this issue. I tried adding an `%include` statement in my `.i` file but I'm getting the same syntax error.

Comment: @citizenSNIPS Keep adding `%include` for any header you need to process.  SWIG doesn't recurse.

Comment: I've found that adding `%include <windows.i>` in the interface file can resolve this issue. see section 3.4 in the swig documentation [HERE](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Windows.html)