# Swig: Syntax error in input(3)

Tags: c, syntax, swig

```
./theheader.h:349: Error: Syntax error in input(3).
```

Offending line:

```
string read_gdbm(GDBM_FILE dbf, string key_str, bool show_err = gbls.verbose);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As I recall, these are often some namespace designation that was left off.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, a syntax error in SWIG means that it can't understand the line in question (which can be annoying, because the line numbers don't follow macros such as `%define`s).  So I suggest you check that `string` (should it be `std::string`? has it been defined?), `GDBM_FILE` (has it been defined? should it be in a namespace?) and maybe `gbls.verbose` (has it been defined?) make sense to SWIG.  It may help to run `swig` with the `-E` option (be sure to redirect the stdout), find the corresponding line and search backward for each type involved.  You may need to add some `#include`s.

Also check the previous line, to ensure you're not missing a semicolon, or something like that.

Answer (score 5):

As a side note, I've run into the same issue for different reasons: I was trying to use a vector < vector < double >>. Now the ">>" character sequence mustn't be used with templates according to the C++99 standard, hence the swig error message popped up. The solution was to simply add an extra space to separate them.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I had no clue why it was saying the my 2d vector had an invalid issue. I would have never figured this out.

Answer (score 4):

I hit a similar error. I'll clarify my process, hope it can be helpful.

**lib.i**:

```
...
%begin %{
#include "header1.h"
%}
...

%include "header1.h"
```

**header1.h**:

```
19 typedef struct T {
   ...
23 } PACKED TlvHdr;
```

The error message just as below

```
./header1.h:23: Error: Syntax error in input(3).
```

I check the SWIG doc(http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html 5.7.1) and found that the syntax error is so common, it's probably caused by a SWIG bug.

The doc recommended when encountering a syntax error to use `#ifndef SWIG` to omit statements that will make SWIG parser issue an error. So I changed the `header1.h` file, then the error disappeared.

**header1.h**:

```
#ifndef SWIG
19 typedef struct T {
   ...
23 } PACKED TlvHdr;
#endif
```

If you can't modify `theheader.h` file, you can make a new header file that just contains the declarations you need and replace the file from `theheader.h` to your new header file at `%include` directive

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and `-E` helped me understand that a macro definition was hidden inside an `#ifndef SWIG` block. I suspect that here it does not see the definition of `GDBM_FILE`,  likely because it [does not recurse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10762949/422797).